# find and click element which has a changing CSS selector (python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a script which needs to click on an element of a page, however, the CSS selector changes everyday as the element changes it's location.

Today it's called:

```
PPTAmFCTable > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(11) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)
```

Yesterday it was:

```
PPTAmFCTable > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(10) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)
```

And tomorrow it might be `tr:nth-child(13)` or so.

I use the following code:

```
def click_element_bycss(browser,css,timeout):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,css)) 
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(element_present)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css).click()
```

and then:

```
click_element_bycss(browser,"#PPTAmFCTable > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(11) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)",4)
```

How can I write the code in a way that I click on the right element, w/o knowing the number in the second tr:nth-child() ?

Element HTML:

```
<a href="/FC1/ItemList;jsessionid=E6B3D538CD809FDDC3DE69EA160C956D?WorkPool=PickingNotYetPicked&amp;ExSDRange.RangeEndMillis=1556850660000&amp;ProcessPath=PPTAmFC&amp;ExSDRange.RangeStartMillis=1556850599999&amp;shipmentType=TRANSSHIPMENTS">261</a>
```

Thought of a loop which just runs through 
for i in range(1,20): tr:nth-child(i) 
but would expect there's something smarter.

Comment: You need to use relative locator instead of the absolute locator. You may need to find the element by text. Post the HTML of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find and click on the element as the element is a dynamic element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#PPTAmFCTable>tbody a[href^='/FC1/ItemList'][href$='TRANSSHIPMENTS']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PPTAmFCTable' and starts-with(@href,'/FC1/ItemList')][contains(@href, 'TRANSSHIPMENTS')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```